# Multi-step form current section do not validate when click to previous button

Tags: jquery

```html
<a href="https://codepen.io/salman-aziz/pen/WWWrov" target="_blank">Code Pen Link</a>
```

Multistep form validates when moving to the previous section is there any way not to validate only when clicking the previous button?

Comment: what are you tried already ? Provide some code please

Comment: This depends greatly on your setup but one option is to `name` the button (e.g. `<button name="previous">Back</button>`) and then in your code have an `if` that avoids the validation step when that button is pressed, e.g. `if ($(e.target).attr('name') === "previous") { ... } else { validation }`

Comment: yes! updated the link